# How to deploy to Apache httpd using Jenkins

Tags: apache, jenkins

When I search "How to deploy to Apache httpd using Jenkins" or similar searches, all I can find is tutorials on how to run Jenkins behind an Apache proxy.

I want to know how to actually deploy my web application to Apache using Jenkins. I must be going about this the wrong way or something because I assumed it would be an extremely common use case, but I can't find any info on it anywhere, and I don't see any Jenkins Apache httpd plugins

Answer (score 1):

You could install a [Jenkins `FTP` plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin) and upload the code to your apache `htdocs` folder. There isn't an Apache API to achieve that.